# How do I update React context from within an onChange handler function

Tags: reactjs, api

There are plenty of examples of changing context directly - such as this:

```
export class UserProvider extends React.Component {
  updateUsername = newUsername => {
    this.setState({ username: newUsername });
  };
  state = {
    username: "user",
    updateUsername: this.updateUsername
  };
}
```

followed by this in the Consumer:

```js
<input
  id="username"
  type="text"
  onChange={event => {
    updateUsername(event.target.value);
  }}
/>
```

but my onChange handler is a function and within that OnChange handler,  I want to update a context variable. 
Using this example, how would I call `updateUsername` from within the OnChange Handler or indeed from any function such as componentDidMoount, etc

I have searched but so far not been able to find anything that might give an indication as to how to accomplish this.

Comment: please provide a full example and not pasting parts of code, refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: And you may be mixing with [React.Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#contextconsumer), you should use the right terms like "How to update in React Element child"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Context in React you'd usually want to have reducers when updating state, reducers allow you to dispatch actions that mutate state repetitively. Don't update state directly it's regarded as anti-pattern.
I wanted to add this a comment however my reputation doesn't allow me to do so yet, excuse me if this doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: Why would it be an anti pattern? I mean, if you defined state and its handler with hooks, you would be able to access both state and its handler within the component that have access to the context.

Comment: In component level state that isn't much of an issue, however as your app grows so does it's complexity therefore managing states would be nearly impossible with just component level. That's why you use state management libraries like redux, context API, unstated etc.